# Why doesn't the max() function run as it is expected?

Tags: python

```
numbers = []

first_input = input('Write any number.When you are done just write "done":')
numbers.append(first_input)

while first_input:
    input_numb = input("Write next number")
    if input_numb == int():
        numbers.append(input_numb)
    elif input_numb == "done":
        print("The largest number is "+max(numbers))
        print("The smallest number is "+min(numbers))
        break
```

Can someone look at this code and tell me what I did wrong please? After I put the input numbers I want to print the biggest and smallest number from the list `numbers` but I don't know why the max function does not return the biggest number, instead it returns the smallest one (just like the `min` function. Why?

Comment: Because it is only getting `first_input` because `input_numb = int()` will be false unless `input_numb` is `False` or `0`.

Comment: You want `type(input_numb) == int` instead.

Comment: @EliSadoff minor nit, `0 == int()` and `False == int()` will return `True` ;)

Comment: @excaza That is true! Lemme fix my comment.

Comment: (Damn default constructors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numbers = []

first_input = input('Write any number.When you are done just write "done":')
numbers.append(int(first_input))

while first_input:
    input_numb = input("Write next number")
    try:
        numbers.append(int(input_numb))
    except:
        if input_numb == "done":
            print("The largest number is ", max(numbers))
            print("The smallest number is ", min(numbers))
            break
        else:
            print('invalid input!')
```

out:

```
Write any number.When you are done just write "done":1
Write next numbera
invalid input!
Write next number2
Write next number3
Write next number6
Write next numberdone
The largest number is  6
The smallest number is  1
```

1. `int()` will return 0:

> class int(x, base=10)
>
> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or
>   **return 0 if no arguments are given**.If x is a number, return x.__int__(). For floating point numbers, this truncates towards
>   zero.

```
In [7]: int() == 0 == False
Out[7]: True
```

2. you should use `max` in a list of number not a list of string, convert string to int before you `append` it to list
3. `"The largest number is " + max(numbers)`
   return :
   `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`, just use `,` to concate the string and int.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert your inputs to integers using `int(my_input)` then add  them to the list `my_list.append(int(my_input))` and use the **max** or **min** functions `max(my_list)`  after getting all the inputs from the user

```
numbers = []

user_input = input('Write any number.When you are done just write "done": ')

while user_input != "done":
     try:
        numbers.append(int(user_input))
        user_input = input("Write next number : ")
     except ValueError:
        user_input = input("please enter a valid number : ")

print("The largest number is ", max(numbers))
print("The smallest number is ", min(numbers))
```